# Is it possible to render an object's "ground shadows" on a separate layer in Blender Render?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, shadows

Lately I've been trying to look for any tutorials on how to make "shadow catcher" planes in Blender Render because I need to render ground shadows on a separate layer. However it seems every tutorial I've come across uses Cycles. But can this be done in Blender Render or not?

No this isn't a duplicate of another question. Yes I have a shadow rendered against a transparent background already, but what I am trying to do is have that shadow on a separate layer. Using Blender Render and not Cycles.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of that question because I am trying to get that shadow onto a separate layer using Blender Render.

Comment: @Terminus_Est, the first (accepted) answer starts with "One quick way to achieve this using Blender Internal is..."